# use scrapy in python to scrap a table with multiple pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

My issue is how to scrap data from a dynamic table (with pages), while when scrolling from one page to another, it does not change the URL website.
https://www.inesss.qc.ca/thematiques/medicaments/medicaments-evaluation-aux-fins-dinscription.html

```
import scrapy
class InesssspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "inesssspider"
    allowed_domains = ["www.inesss.qc.ca"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.inesss.qc.ca/thematiques/medicaments/medicaments-evaluation-aux-fins-dinscription.html#jfmulticontent_c767-6"]

    def parse(self, response):
        table_rows = response.css('tr.even, tr.odd')
        print(len(table_rows))
        for table_row in table_rows:
                yield {
                    'DATE': table_row.css('td:nth-child(1)::text').get(),

                    'Nomcommercial/Projet': table_row.css('td:nth-child(2) a::text, td:nth-child(2)::text ').get(),
                    'Dénominationcommune/Sujet': table_row.css('td:nth-child(3) a::text, td:nth-child(3)::text ').get(),

                    'Fabricant': table_row.css('td:nth-child(4)::text').get(),
                    'RecommandationINESSS': table_row.css('td:nth-child(5)::text').get(),
                    'DécisionMinistre': table_row.css('td:nth-child(6)::text').get(),
                }

        next_page = response.css('ul.pager__list li.pager__page a.page-link.solr-ajaxified::attr(href)').get()
        if next_page:
            next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page_url, callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try viewing the source code, this website isn't showing any dynamic table, rather it's using javascript for updating classes and elements. If you view the source code, you will see exact classes/ids which scrapy sees!